# Automatically generate .factorypath on project import when using Maven project in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, annotation-processing

The `.factorypath` file is a generated file, which eclipse requires for annotation-processing. The `m2eclipse` plugin does generate this file when using "Update Maven Project" (Alt+F5) and checking "Update project configuration from `pom.xml`".

However, I don't want to check this file into version control. But if not, and someone from the team does a fresh checkout, and imports the project in eclipse, the `.factorypath` does not get generated until the  "Update Maven Project" is performed manually. I don't want this manual step when a project gets imported, this has to happen automatically. Is there an option, that a project has to be updated upon import?

Answer (score 4):

Since this is an IDE related question, and you seem to be using Eclipse IDE:

Menu `Window` > `Preferences` > `Maven` > `Automatically update Maven projects configuration` .

This will make it for you on project import so you would not need that manual step anymore.

Comment: Unfortunately this experimental feature does not automatically generate the `.factorypath` file in an imported project. (eclipse 2020-06 / 4.16.0, m2e 1.16.0.20200610-1735 )

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your real issue is

> I don't want to check this file into version control.

Though you have not specified which version control you are using but if you are a GIT or SVN user, you need to add files/directories pattern in GIT ignore file or SVN ignore properties.

Read more on [GIT Ignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) or [SVN Ignore](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html).

Comment: What? The problem is not that!

Comment: we know it can be ignore... what we want to know how that file is generated?

Comment: While this doesn't answer the question asked, it is part of what is needed and it does answer a question others who find this question are probably asking.